# Conditional summing of columns

Tags: r

I have two columns as follows:

```
structure(list(V1 = c(2344, NA, 100, 43), V2 = c(122, 
322, NA, 33), col3 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_)), .Names = c("V1", "V2", "col3"), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), class = "data.frame")
```

I want to add `V1` to `V2` in a new columns only if one of them has a `NA` in it. otherwise I will take `V1`'s value.

Expected output:

```
    V1  V2 col3
1 2344 122   2344
2   NA 322   322
3  100  NA   100
4   43  33   43
```

I tried:

```
TBB$col3<-ifelse(is.na(TBB$V1)|is.na(TBB$V2),sum(TBB$V1,TBB$V2),TBB$V1)
```

but it has given me

```
    V1  V2 col3
1 2344 122   NA
2   NA 322   NA
3  100  NA   NA
4   43  33   NA
```

Comment: Why is row 3 = 200 in your desired result?

Comment: Sorry. Typo. Corrected now. Should be 100

Answer (score 1):

We can do this with `max.col`

```
TBB$col3 <- TBB[,1:2][cbind(1:nrow(TBB), max.col(!is.na(TBB[,1:2]), "first"))]
TBB$col3
#[1] 2344  322  100   43
```

Answer (score 0):

There's something weird about the structure value since it's specification for rownames is longer that the number of values of any column, so I fixed that and then my code was successful

```
TBB <- structure(list(V1 = c(2344, NA, 100, 43), V2 = c(122, 
 322, NA, 33), col3 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
 NA_real_)), .Names = c("V1", "V2", "col3"), row.names = c(NA, 
 -4L), class = "data.frame")

 ifelse( !rowSums(is.na(TBB[1:2])), TBB$V1, rowSums(TBB, na.rm=TRUE) )
[1] 2344  322  100   43
```

Uses the logically coerced value of !rowSums(is.na(.)) which will only be TRUE when there are no NAs, in which case you want V1, otherwise you want what `rowSums` with na.rm